# OpenCL detection bug

Tags: rendering, opencl, adobe-premiere, amd-gpu

I'm new to Adobe Premiere and GPU acceleration. I started to follow simple tutorial on editing video with Premiere Pro CC that I had "Stopped Working" error after seconds when I hovered on my video or dragged it. Found that problem is because of OpenCL. So I put my settings to "Software Only" to have just CPU rendering.

My hardware and software:

- HP ProBook 450 G1
- Microsoft Windows 8.1 X64
- AMD Radeon 8600/8700M
- 14.12 AMD Catalyst Omega Software
- Intel HD 4600
- AMD APP SDK 2.9
- Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013

(For web developing. I'm not a CPP programmer.)

- Adobe Premiere Pro CC

I used GPU-Z to have details about my AMD GPU and I saw that OpenCL is disabled and other one (Intel) is enabled.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1y4A0.gif)

So I used `/program files/adobe/adobe premiere pro cc/gpusniffer.exe` and this is the output:

```
Found 2 devices supporting GPU computation.
OpenCL Device 0 -
   Name: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600
   Vendor: Intel
   Capability: 1.2
   Driver: 1.2
   Total Video Memory: 1348MB
   * Not enabled by default because it did not match the named list of cards.
OpenCL Device 1 -
   Name: Oland
   Vendor: AMD
   Capability: 2
   Driver: 1.2
   Total Video Memory: 2048MB
```

I read all the docs of APP SDK but I didn't find anything except this one:

Output of `/windows/system32/clinfo.exe`

```
 Compiler available:                            Yes
 Execution capabilities:
   Execute OpenCL kernels:                      Yes
   Execute native function:                     No
 Queue properties:
   Out-of-Order:                                No
   Profiling :                                  Yes
 Platform ID:                                   00007FFBA45D6B60
 Name:                                          Oland
 Vendor:                                        Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
 Device OpenCL C version:                       OpenCL C 1.2
 Driver version:                                1642.5 (VM)
 Profile:                                       FULL_PROFILE
 Version:                                       OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1642.5)
```

What should I do in order to enable OpenCL in GPU-Z for my AMD Radeon GPU?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After two weeks Googling for my problem I found my answer in playing with `regedit`.
To have fun with `OpenCL` on `Windows 8.1` and `AMD Radeon` we must do these:

1. **Only** use `AMD Catalyst Control Center` downloaded from AMD official website. (For me, installer downloaded from `HP Support Center` didn't work. I think because it didn't contains some packages.)
2. Download and install `AMD APP SDK` from `AMD Developers` official website.
3. Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP SDK\`**2.9**`\bin`. (It will be different based on your version.)
4. Copy and replace files from `x86` folder (`OpenCL.dll` and `amdocl.dll`) to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.
5. Copy and replace files from `x86_64` folder (`OpenCL.dll` and `amdocl64.dll`) to `C:\Windows\System32`.
   *Note: `OpenCL.dll` files are different with each other. Pay attention.*
6. Open `Start` and type `regedit` in `search` or `RUN`.
7. Go to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Khronos\OpenCL\Vendors\`.
8. Add `amdocl64.dll` as `DWORD (32-bit) Value`. (Do not edit it after creation!)
9. Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Khronos\OpenCL\Vendors\`.
10. Add `amdocl.dll` as `DWORD (32-bit) Value`.
11. Restart windows (Because of `Catalyst`) and start `Catalyst`.
12. In `Premiere` go to `File -> Project Settings -> General -> Video Rendering and Playback` and set `Renderer` to `Mercury Playback Engine GPU Acceleration (OpenCL)`.

***Note: In `Registry Editor`, `0` means `true` (enabled) and `1` means `false` (disabled) for `OpenCL`.***

***Note: `regedit` must run as administrator.***

Done! `Adobe Premiere Pro CC` works fast and fine. ***Note: `GPU-Z` will not show OpenCL enabled. I think because its old version.***

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87qNk.png)

Comment: A working AMD system with both CPU and GPU, should have two entries in Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Khronos\OpenCL\Vendors\. One is simply amdocl.dll presumably for CPU and another pointing to driverstore for GPU eg: "C:\\Windows\\System32\\DriverStore\\FileRepository\\c0321058.inf_amd64_c0aa1a2b512afe19\\amdocl64.dll"=dword:00000000 this is automatic from installing Radeon driver setup.exe